# DNN error "Could not load file or assembly" from MVC module, despite correcting the Module program

Tags: asp.net-mvc, module, dotnetnuke

I added v7.0 of Microsoft.Extensions ... packages and then reverted back to V2.0, then build the MVC module project as release, and run to get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I realized that there is a mismatch in the installed packages and project web.config, So I uninstalled all packages except default project template packages using this command:

```
uninstall-package -Id YourPackageId -removedependencies -Force
```

Then forget about using these packages and Release build project and run. also web.config and packages folder in the project, Now look good (without offending packages).

Again I get the error. Why I still get this error? Another thing I tried, removing DNN module manually but using this stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetDesktopModulePermissionsByPortalDesktopModuleID]
        @PortalDesktopModuleID = 81

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I get 0 permissions to remove!

How to fix this error?